# NoSuchElementException Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

This is a simple program that I wrote to do calculations on integers from a txt file. After a few hours of trying to debug, I was hoping a fresh set of eyes could spot a few of my problems. EDIT: data.txt contains integers 1-5. One integer per line.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

public static int[] NUMBERS;    //global value for the array

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("data.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

    List x = new ArrayList();

    while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        x.add(sc.nextInt());
    }

    NUMBERS = new int[x.size()];
    Iterator<Integer> iterator = x.iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBERS.length; i++) {
        NUMBERS[i] = iterator.next().intValue();
    }

    sc.close();

    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(file);

    System.out.println("Welcome to Calculation Program!\n");
    startMenus(sc2);

}

private static void startMenus(Scanner sca) throws FileNotFoundException {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("(Enter option # and press ENTER)\n");

        System.out.println("1. Display the average of the list");
        System.out.println("2. Display the number of occurences of a given element in the list");
        System.out.println("3. Display the prime numbers in a list");
        System.out.println("4. Display the information above in table form");
        System.out.println("5. Save the information onto a file in table form");
        System.out.println("6. Exit");

        int option = sca.nextInt();

        sca.nextLine();

        switch (option) {
            case 1:
                infoMenu1(sca);
                break;
            case 2:
                infoMenu2(sca);
                break;
            case 3:
                infoMenu3(sca);
                break;
            case 4:
                infoMenu4(sca);
                break;
            case 5:
                infoMenu5(sca);
                break;
            case 6:
                System.exit(0);
            default:

                System.out.println("Unrecognized Option!\n");
        }

    }
}

private static void infoMenu1(Scanner sc2) {
    System.out.println("The average of the numbers in the file is: " + avg(NUMBERS));
}

public static double avg(int[] numbers) {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        sum = (sum + numbers[i]);
    }

    return (sum / numbers.length);
}

public static int occr(int[] numbers, int x) {
    int count = 0;

    for (int n : numbers) {
        if (n == x) {
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }

    return count;
}

public static boolean prime(int x) {
    boolean answer = true;

    if (x == 0 || x == 1) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 2; i <= x / 2; i = i + 1) {
        if (i != x) {
            if (x % i == 0) {
                answer = false;
            }
        }
    }

    return answer;
}

public static int[] primes(int[] numbers) {
    int primesCount = 0;

    for (int i : numbers) {
        if (prime(i)) {
            primesCount = (primesCount + 1);
        }
    }

    if (primesCount == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    int[] result = new int[primesCount];
    int index = 0;

    for (int i : numbers) {
        if (prime(i)) {
            result[index] = i;
            index = index + 1;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

private static void infoMenu2(Scanner sc) {
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Which integer would you like to check for number of occurences?");
    int choice = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println("The number of occurence(s) of " + choice + " are/is " + occr(NUMBERS, choice));


}

private static void infoMenu3(Scanner sc2) {
    int[] myPrimes = primes(NUMBERS);

    System.out.println("The prime number(s) in the file are/is: ");

    for (int j = 0; j < myPrimes.length; ++j) {
        System.out.println(myPrimes[j] + " ");
    }

}

private static void infoMenu4(Scanner kb) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("data.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

    int counter = 0;
    while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        counter = counter++;
    }

    int lenth = counter;

    int[] column1 = new int[lenth];
    while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        column1 = new int[sc.nextInt()];
    }

    int[] column2 = new int[occr(NUMBERS, sc.nextInt())];

    boolean column3 = prime(sc.nextInt());

    System.out.printf("Average: " + "%20.2f", column1);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("Occurences: " + "%14d", column2);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("Primes:" + "%19s : %s", column3);
    System.out.println();
}

private static void infoMenu5(Scanner kb) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("data.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("results.txt"));

    int counter = 0;
    while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        counter = counter++;
    }

    int lenth = counter;

    int[] column1 = new int[lenth];
    while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        column1 = new int[sc.nextInt()];
    }

    int[] column2 = new int[occr(NUMBERS, sc.nextInt())];

    boolean column3 = prime(sc.nextInt());

    pw.printf("Number: " + "%-10d", column1);
    pw.println();
    pw.printf("Occurences: " + "%12d", column2);
    pw.println();
    pw.printf("Primes:" + "%24s : %s", column3);
    pw.println();

    pw.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post `data.txt` content?

Comment: Where are you getting the problem? Line number

Comment: As your main program shows only main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException , you need to show us the whole program. Because we have to understand where the NoSuchElementException is occuring.

Comment: @lancer: I just run the application with data.txt contains 5 line and no exception is happen

Comment: @IswantoSan data.txt contains integers 1-5. One integer per line.

Comment: Please post the exception trace.

Comment: Did you give the entire path for data.txt file ?

Comment: @lancer..Yes I try using that

Comment: can you post the stack trace, it is working for me

Comment: I have posted the entire code.

Comment: I modified the code so I do not get the exception anymore, but it chooses options even before I enter anything to the keyboard. If I consume two lines, it gives me the same NoSuchElementException. Please help.

Comment: your `infoMenu4` is the problem

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong Scanner in your code (line 49). I suppose you are trying to get user input. However, you are using Scanner to get input from data.txt.

Updated according to the comments. Actually, you don't need Scanner from data.txt in startMenus. What you need is user input. So change sc2 to Scanner from System.in.

Original line 31:

```
// Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(file);
Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: That fixes a major problem. Thank you so much